# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when importing from csv in Laravel

Tags: laravel, import-csv

I'm getting **Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails** when importing from csv in Laravel

Updating existing rows work but creating new rows gives me the error.

Migration:

```
    {
        Schema::create('statements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('employeenumber')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('employeenumber')->references('employee_number')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'employeenumber',
        'name',
        'address',
    ];
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'employeenumber';

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User','employeenumber','employee_number');
    }
```

Import Controller

```
$employee = Employee::updateOrCreate(
            ['employeenumber' => $row['employeenumber']],
            [
                'name'      => $row['name'],
                'address'   => $row['address'],
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Try to `try .. catch..` updateOrCreate() and print problematic data out.

Comment: Please post your `users` table too.